# ISO/IEC TR 18037 (fixed-point arithmetic): no signed zero?

Tags: c, zero, fixed-point

In [ISO/IEC TR 18037:2006(E)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1169.pdf) I don't see if there is a signed zero.

Consider this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    _Sat short _Fract x, y;
    x = 0.0078125HR;   // SFRACT_EPSILON
    y = x * x;         // 0.0HR
    y = -x * x;        // -0.0078125HR
}
```

Questions:

1. If anyone knows: why there is no signed zero?
2. If `-x * x` is `-SFRACT_EPSILON`, then why `x * x` is `0.0HR` instead of `SFRACT_EPSILON`?

Comment: On page 66, it says “… this Technical Report requires exclusively two's complement behaviour for fixed-point arithmetic.” Two’s complement has no signed zero.

Comment: Thanks! Also I see that `0b10000000` is reserved for `SFRACT_MIN`, which is `(-0.5HR-0.5HR)`. Also: should not be confused: e.g. `FLT_MIN` (minimum normalized _positive_ floating-point number) with e.g. `SFRACT_MIN` (minimum value for an object of type `signed short _Fract` ).